# open a unicode name file on linux from Python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, unicode, filesystems

I was trying to open a file on Ubuntu in Python using:-

```
open('<unicode_string>', "wb")
```

unicode_string is '\u9879\u76ee\u7ba1\u7406'. It is a Chinese text.
But I get the following error:-

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I am trying to understand what limits this behavior? Went through some links. I understand that the OS's filesystem has the responsibility to encode the string. For windows the 'mbcs' encoding handles possibly every character. What could be the problem with linux.

- Does not fail for all linux setups. What should I be checking?

Comment: What is your `locale` (type that command, show its output)? Notably `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables?

Comment: just trying to understand how would locale affect this behavior? Can you please shed some light. Is it that the file system is trying to encode as per locale settings?

Comment: The error you get is from the Python layer. The [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall does not care about encoding.

Comment: <a href='http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding'>filesystem encoding</a>. As per this I thought filesystem gets the unicode string as in my question and then encodes it as per its convenience.

Comment: And True that this is a Python error(As I can see a clean TraceBack on console). But I suspect that to store the unicode filename, Python must be encoding the name in the type of encoding obtained from OS/filesystem

Comment: `mbcs` does not handle every character, it would limit you to characters in the ANSI code page for that machine. However Python has special support for accepting pathnames as Unicode strings and passing those directly to Win32-specific APIs instead of using the C standard library calls with `mbcs` encoding.

Comment: On non-Windows platforms, Unicode pathnames have to be converted to byte strings in the Python layer. Python uses the machine's locale information to try to work out what encoding is used for file system paths. On a modern Linux system that encoding should be UTF-8 to make everyone happy, but something about your environment is making Python think you are using Latin-1 for your filesystem, in which case storing U+9879 et al is indeed impossible.

Comment: Yes probably you are right. But I am trying to figure out what is that something :( . locale shows 'utf-8'. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` also returns utf-8. I am not able to figure out that 'something' because of which Python may be assuming encoding to be 'latin-1'. Is there something else to check that I am missing?

Comment: Could you test `open(u'\u9879\u76ee\u7ba1\u7406'.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding(), "wb"))` ? It could be a workaround, definitely not explaining, why Python seems confused about system encoding. Note, that IDE could sometime create alternative environment, using another encoding, e.g. on Czech Windows I had "cp-1250" on console, but "utf-8" in my IDE (PyDev).